# CMake fails to create directory with a specific name `models`

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to create custom directories and copy files into a test folder during the build process of CMake. (This is needed so I can conveniently run a test script that tests another executable which requires certain directories to be available. The target does not actually build any real outputs.)

The goal is to create empty directories called `models` and `logs` in the build directory of my target, `custom-test`.

The CMake command I am using in `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_custom_target(custom-test ALL
   COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory models logs
)
# Copy files into build dir and the dirs created above
configure_file("config.json" . COPYONLY)
configure_file("temp-model.txt" ./models COPYONLY)
```

When I build, the `logs` directory is always created successfully, but weirdly the `models` directory always produces a build error:

```
Error creating directory "models".
make[2]: *** [tests/custom-test/CMakeFiles/custom-test.dir/build.make:71: tests/custom-test/CMakeFiles/custom-test] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:451: tests/custom-test/CMakeFiles/custom-test.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

If I run `ls -l tests/custom-test` from the BUILD directory, I can see the following entries, which shows that `logs` was created but `models` is some kind of dead filepath:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 reid reid 4096 Nov  1 10:58 logs
-rw-rw-r-- 1 reid reid    0 Nov  1 10:58 models
```

**My question is** why is it only failing to create the `models` directory? I tried renaming the directory name to `modelsdir` and other names instead and those all seem to work. But my other applications that I am testing expect there to be a directory called `models`.

**Possibly important side-note:** Previously, in my source code I had a subdirectory called `models` that created a cmake library target `models`. I have since completely refactored this to another name since I thought cmake might be getting confused, even though that library was unrelated to this test target. I have deleted and regenerated my build directory several times since the refactor which has not helped.

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

**EDIT** I actually think it may have more to do with the `configure_file` commands that copy into the newly created directory.

Comment: "... but `models` is some kind of dead filepath" - Why dead? According to the `ls` output you have a **regular file** named `models`. As you could guess, having a file prevents CMake to create a **directory** with the same name. The file is probably created by that command: `configure_file("temp-model.txt" ./models COPYONLY)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes it is a file. I said dead because it's empty, and I have no idea why it's a file. Every time I test this I delete the whole directory first. But `add_custom_target` command happens first, THEN `configure_file`, so I would think that the directory `models` would be created, and then the `temp-model.txt` file gets copied INTO `models`. Unless I am misunderstanding the way that these CMake functions work, which is highly possible